# Why won't the margin-top property update using jQuery.animate?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm playing around with jQuery for the first time, making a little photo slider plugin to get my feet wet. I can't seem to get the margin-top property to update on my  tags. I thought the margins were collapsing, but now I'm not so sure. Please show me the light!

I was thinking the problem was with the the 10px margin on .slider-frame and the -58px margin on .photo-slider, but if they collapsed, they should result in -48px margin between, right? Using firebug, when I hover over the image, the margin-top property never changes from 10px.

This is the HTML that I'm generating:

```
<div id="photos" class="photo-slider-container">
  <div class="photo-slider">
    <img class="slider-frame" src="images/test-image.jpg"/>
    <img class="slider-frame" src="images/test-image-2.jpg"/>
    <img class="slider-frame" src="images/test-image-3.jpg"/>
    <img class="slider-frame" src="images/test-image-4.jpg"/>
    <img class="slider-frame" src="images/test-image-5.jpg"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the extracted CSS, generated with jQuery, to make it easier for you to read:

```
.photo-slider-container{
    overflow: hidden; 
    visibility: visible; 
    position: relative; 
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    height: 216px; 
    width: 800px; 
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
}

.photo-slider {
    margin: -58px 0px 0px -580px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 1160px;
}

.slider-frame {
 margin: 10px 5px; 
 float: left; 
 width: 96px; 
 height: 96px;
}
```

this is the hover code:

```
$(this).hover(
  function(){
   $(this).stop().animate({
      "height" : opts.large_image_height,
      "width" : opts.large_image_width,
      "margin-top" : opts.large_image_height / -2 + "px"
    }, { duration : 250 })
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({
      "height" : opts.small_image_height,
      "width" : opts.small_image_width,
      "margin-top" : "10px"
    }, { duration : 250 })
  }
);
```

**Edit**
put up on [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/odefo)

Comment: can you post a demo on http://jsbin.com ?

Comment: How are opts.large_image_height, etc calculated? Could we see the script that calculates those too?

Comment: that jsbin.com is pretty neat! thanks Russ.

Comment: Do you use the latest jQuery?

Comment: @Matt - No probs, jsbin has been great for quickly trying out ideas and collaborating over code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh - it's **marginTop.** - I guess the internal animation parser doesn't translate the 'margin-top' to the *real* marginTop.

Example: http://jsbin.com/uxazo

Note: Your script will fail in IE because you have trailing commas inside of your objects:

```
{
one:1,
two:2, <---- get rid of this.
}
```

Comment: .. what does the height evaluate to. you can solve this problem easily by simplifying this...

Comment: yeah, I know about the trailing comma. thanks. now I just need to get the math right.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm too late - it's `marginTop` not `margin-top` inside of `animate()`. Was it **[something like this](http://jsbin.com/inona)** you were looking for?

I'll answer anyway as another improvement that you might consider is caching `$(this)` inside a local variable in the `each()` commands, i.e.

```
    return this.each(function() { 

  Cache this ->  $(this).wrap("<div></div>"); 
                 slider_container = $(this).parent();
```

now becomes

```
    return this.each(function() { 
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.wrap("<div></div>"); 
        slider_container = $this.parent();
```

This means that a new jQuery object isn't being constructed each time you call `$()` passing in `this`

Comment: thanks. I'll remember that. This is closer to what I was going for, but it's still not centered correctly if you want to take a stab:
http://jsbin.com/ipote

Comment: no probs, happy to help :) I'd recommend getting a hold of jQuery in Action if you can as there's a few good pointers in there about plugin authoring. Also take a look at http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/making-a-jquery-plugin-truly-customizable#more-641, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring and http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/the-definitive-guide-to-creating-a-practical-jquery-plugin/